# Can't CONNECT to Postgresql after upgrading from 8.1?

Tags: postgresql

Why can't my users connect to their normal Postgresql databases after upgrading from 8.1 to 8.4? Was a permission lost in the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The `CONNECT` privilege was added in Postgresql 8.2 so it is not present in backups from earlier versions. You need to `GRANT` it after the upgrade like so:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE foo TO bar;
```